# How do I check if the current password that the user gives in the password reset form matches with the hashed password in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to reset a user password programmatically in Drupal 8 without the email link. For this the first step would be to check if the password(which is plain) that the user enters in the password reset form is matching with the hashed password of the respective user. And then save the new password.

Each time I hash the password, its giving a different value, this is because its salted. How shall I compare the password which the user enters in the form with the hashed password from the table.

This is the code that I have in my controller for checking the current password :

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* contains \Drupal\customer_profile\Controller\ProfileUpdateController
*/

 namespace Drupal\customer_profile\Controller;

 use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
 use Drupal\Core\Password\PhpassHashedPassword;
 use Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface;

 class ProfileUpdateController extends ControllerBase {

   //$user = User::load(1);
   //$user->setPassword('secret');
   //$pass = $user->save();
   $user =\Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
   $ret = \Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface::check('secret', $user);

   $response->password = $ret;
   return new JsonResponse($response);
  }
 }
```

After using **\Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface::check()** method, for comparing the plain text password with the hash password, I get this fatal error :

**Fatal error: Non-static method Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface::check() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\ijarah\modules\custom\customer_profile\src\Controller\ProfileUpdateController.php on line 725**

In Drupal 7 we have **user_check_password** to check the password with string and **user_hash_password** for hashing. 
How can I approach the same in Drupal 8.

Please help.

Comment: I've also tried using **\Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface::check()** with no luck. A fatal error is returned saying , **_Fatal error: Non-static method Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface::check() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\ijarah\modules\custom\customer_profile\src\Controller\ProfileUpdateController.php on line 725_** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution would be to use the Dependency Injection and then use the check() method. Here is the code :

```
<?php    
/**
* @file
* contains \Drupal\customer_profile\Controller\ProfileUpdateController
*/
namespace Drupal\customer_profile\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface;

 class ProfileUpdateController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {

  public function __construct(PasswordInterface $password_hasher, AccountInterface $account) {
   $this->passwordHasher = $password_hasher;
   $this->account = $account;
  }

   public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
     return new static(
       $container->get('password'),
       $container->get('current_user')
     );
   }

   public function updatePassword() {
     //global $user;
     $response = new \stdClass();
      //check the plain password with the hashed password from db
     $pass = $this->passwordHasher->check('secret', 'hashed_password_from_db');

     $response->password = $pass;
     // this will return true if the password matches or false vice-versa
     return new JsonResponse($response);
   }
  }
   ?>
```

After checking the password, we can save the new password using

```
  $user = User::load(1);
  $user->setPassword('new_password_secret');
  $user->save();
```

Hope this helps others :)